# udev disk mount permissions in linux

Tags: linux, udev, embedded, automounting

We would like to set up a customer account on our overo running embedded Angstrom along with ssh so they can log on to retrieve data.

```
uname -a
Linux pb014-01 2.6.32 #1 Wed Feb 29 15:17:02 GMT 2012 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

(where pb014-01 should probably read Overo) this is the only version we have all our drivers compiled for.

The customer data is located on fat32 formatted external usb or sd mass storage devices, (micro sd(mmcblk0p1) + usb sd(sd[a-z][0-1])).

The devices/volumes are mounted by udev automatically so the device/folder names are unknown at device setup.

Currently the permissions of the folder in /media are

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root     0 Aug  6 16:44 sdb1
```

I think I need at least drwxr-xrwx

I have added a custom rule to send a udp command to our software to notify of disk adds + removes, so we stop writing immediately to a folder in /media if the disk is removed.

As a hack I suppose, on udev adds, I could make it chmod -R the permissions we need but hope there is a neater way to get udev to mount it with the correct permission in the first place.

I have tried adding fmask umash dmask uid optons to automount() in /etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh to no avail (maybe I formatted them wrong if this should be the solution)

A lot of the answered questions are concerning restricting permissions rather than "adding" permissions which I am trying to achieve.

While trying to google for answers I see a lot of people mentioning gvfs and nautilus so I wonder if there is another disk mounting program that I am unaware of that is doing the actual work

If not I hope someone

Many Thanks
G

Comment: Have you looked at `udisks`? Would it do what you want it to?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, can you explain how it might work? would I have  monitor disks added through udev then unmount then remount using udisks to get the permissions I want?

Or do you mean modify the current udev mount script to use udisks instead of mount? as my issue is I don't know if the place I think the disk is being mounted really is the correct line. Your other post [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72437/how-to-grant-non-root-user-access-to-device-files/72446#72446) ?

Comment: I'm wondering if I could do this with no Vid and Pid and use block device or matching sd[a-z][0-9] as I matched for my udp command?

I don't really want to change the owner, just set permissions or as you wrote MODE="0777" instead of 755 which they currently seem to be.

Thanks, G

Comment: So it turns out by editing the line in automount() in /etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh
did work, I just must have been editing it wrong.
Previously I have been adding fmask & dmask options wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out by editing the line in automount() in /etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh
did work, I just must have been editing it wrong.
Originally the line (25) looks like this

```
if ! $MOUNT -t auto -o async,relatime $DEVNAME "/media/$name"
```

Previously I have been adding fmask & dmask options wrongly.

```
if ! $MOUNT -t auto -o async,relatime,fmask=0777,dmask=0777 $DEVNAME "/media/$name"
```

Now it is as I want

```
if ! $MOUNT -t auto -o async,relatime,fmask=0000,dmask=0000 $DEVNAME "/media/$name"
```

I think before I also may not have rebooted the system, only unplugged and replugged the disk or something but this seems to do what I am after