# Giving read permissions to device file of disk

Tags: permissions, devices

If for benchmarking purposes one has to use `hdparm` or `dd` directly on the device, I wonder what the correct way would be to do this safely.

Let's say the disk in question is `/dev/sda`:

```
root@igloo:~# ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 May 29 08:23 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 May 29 08:23 /dev/sda1
```

I really don't want to *write* to `sda` under any circumstances. So would it be advised to do `chmod o+r /dev/sda*` and run `dd` or `hdparm` on it as a normal user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`chmod o+r /dev/sda*` is quite dangerous, as it allows any program to read your whole disk (including e.g. password hashes in `/etc/shadow`, if your root partition is on `sda`)!

There are (at least) two ways to do this more safely:

1. Add all users that need to read the disk to the `disk` group and run `chmod g-w /dev/sda*` to prevent write access for that group.
2. Change the group of `/dev/sda*` to a group that only contains the users that need to read the disk, e.g. `chgrp my-benchmarkers /dev/sda*` and prevent write access for this group with `chmod`.

Please note that the group and permission changes on device nodes in `/dev` are only temporary until the device in question is disconnected or the computer is rebooted.

One problem could be that `hdparm` needs write access for most of its functionality. You must check if everything you want works with read-only access.

**EDIT:** It looks like `hdparm` doesn't need write access. It rather needs the `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` [capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) to perform most ioctls.
You can use `setcap cap_sys_rawio+ep /sbin/hdparm` to give this capability to hdparm. Please note that this allows *anyone* who can execute `hdparm` and has at least read access to a device file to do practically anything `hdparm` can do on that device, including `--write-sector` and all other hdparm commands the man page describes as "VERY DANGEROUS", "EXTREMELY DANGEROUS" or "EXCEPTIONALLY DANGEROUS". Wrapper scripts might be a better solution.

If not you either have to give write access or write wrapper scripts that can be executed by your users as root using sudo rules.

Comment: Good answer. I was going to add something similar until it occurred to me that changes made to the ownership and permissions might only persist until the next reboot. I then got side-tracked into researching how to modify `udev` rules (something I've never had to do, myself).

Comment: Yes, for persistence `udev` rules would be the best way. As the question named benchmarking purposes, I assume that there is no need for a completely permanent solution. Luckily there are quite a few answers about udev rules on similar questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72446/147970

Answer (score 3):

One possibility, although some deployments of /dev might not support it, would be to use an ACL. Example:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M count=200 of=/dev/null
dd: failed to open '/dev/sda': Permission denied
$ sudo setfacl -m u:youruser:r /dev/sd*
$ dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M count=200 of=/dev/null
200+0 records in
200+0 records out
209715200 bytes (210 MB, 200 MiB) copied, 0.0335544 s, 6.3 GB/s
```

AFAIK `hdparm -t` needs to be run as root though.