# Cannot create New folder and Paste files on a drive - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, partition, partition-table

[image]
My Files drive is not able to modify

[image]

Comment: What format is sda2? Are you mounting in fstab? What permissions & ownership do you have? Post this above: `lsblk -f` https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup

Comment: You tagged `Ubuntu` and `linux-mint` which are two different flavors. Please check your tags.

Comment: Open file manager with sudo command ```sudo nautilus``` from the terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Giving read permissions to device file of disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367893/giving-read-permissions-to-device-file-of-disk)

Answer (score 2):

**I am using Windows as second OS, In that case**
My File System was Read Only File System.

My FileSystem was Locked. Might be due to unexpected Windows Shutdown.

**This is not required in some case /dev/sda is visible from above**
I got the Partition from complete storage using :(Path will be /dev/sda[Number] check the Type)

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then it is due to Windows. Then I gave a shot

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda[ntfs_partition_number]
```

Later I just **Clicked on Mount and Unmount**
.

Comment: wow, this worked. even it didnt gave sdb1 in fdisk, but only sbd, but sbd didnt work gave error, but sdb1 worked. weird that it worked

Comment: You have to mention the partition number too, eg. sdb1 . It is the storage partition space, you will be able to fetch write access. I am delighted it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possibilities.

1. As @[Deepak Gaur](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/440921/deepak-gaur) mentioned, it could be permissions.
2. It could be that the filesystem itself is read only.  This is typically because it was mounted that way, but could also be by design, like the ISO9660 filesystem.
3. It could be that the filesystem is corrupt.  Check the output of `dmesg` to see if the kernel reported anything about this.
4. It could be that you have a network filesystem where the remote server doesn't allow access.  (Unlikely as OP describes the problem.)
5. It could be that there are problems accessing the drive.  This could mean a flash drive has been disconnected, or a RAID drive has had too many component drives fail.
6. There could be extended attributes giving you grief (like an immutable directory).
7. There could be extended security attributes, such as for SELinux.
8. The filesystem could be full.
9. There could be otherwise unknown bugs (highly unlikely), or other issues I haven't thought of.

Recommendation:
Get a command line in the relevant directory, and try commands like `mkdir somename` and `touch anothername`, and `ls` to see if they worked.
The error messages should be informative.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission problem. A newly formatted partition will initially be owned by root since the root user is the only one that can do that. What's needed is for you to claim ownership of the file system.

If that partition is mounted say to /media/Downloads then in the terminal run sudo chown -v $USER:$USER /media/Downloads

$USER is an environment variable that resolves to your user id.

Comment: `chown: changing group of '/media/jayanta/New Volume': Read-only file system
failed to change ownership of '/media/jayanta/New Volume'` I tried your solution and getting this.